# Django - Disable form select field validation for a drop down

Tags: django, python-3.x

How do I disable the form field validation for the drop down list?  In .js file I use Ajax return the json data from database and populate it to the drop down list. When I try to save the form it gave me this validation error.

[image]

In the forms.py:

```
class CreateAForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    DUMMY_LIST =[]
    ptvb_dept= forms.ChoiceField(choices= DUMMY_LIST)
```

In views.py:

```
@login_required
def json_ptvb_dept(request):
    sql = """ select category as dept from tablename order by 1;"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, teradata_con()) 
    df_dept = df[['dept']].drop_duplicates()  
    dic = {'dept':[]}
    for index, row in df_dept.iterrows():        
        dic['dept'].append(row['dept'])  
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dic))
```

Comment: does the json response use ids and descriptions? you may need to have the ids in the options, and description (Bulk Foods) as the text.

Comment: Also, on is_valid how does Python know what is a valid choice? if it is based on another field in the form, you may need to use the init method to set up valid choices when validating.

Comment: @AMG  Thank you! I'm new to django. The json return look like this:  {"dept": ["Bulk Foods", "Cosmetics"]}. Later on, I will use the selected value in sql like "where ColumnName=SelectedValue".  Should I do this you mean:   {"1":" bulk food", "2": "Cosmetics"]} ?   Can you show me how to use the init method to set up valid choices? one more thing, the valid choices will change over time too.

Comment: Can you post the views.py method that you are using to generate the json response. Couple of tweaks here and there and we'll get you sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are two conceptions about "form fields": actually [form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/) (these are guys who implement all validation and ORM transformations) and [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets) (how to render them on frontend).

Every standard form field already associated with it's default widget, but you could specify it:

```
ptvb_dept = forms.TextField(widget=widgets.Select)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked!!! ptvb_dept = forms.CharField(widget= widgets.Select)